# Javascript adding HTML element if conditions is true

Tags: javascript

Im having a hard time understanding Javascript. I created a Shopping Cart and i want to display inside a `span` that there is no item inside the cart yet. I managed to accomplish half of this with

```
function CartIsEmpty() {
    let emptyCart = `<span class='empty-cart'>Looks Like You Haven't Added Any Product In The Cart</span>`;
    *// wrapps all the rows inside the cart*
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_list')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart_item')
    if (cartRows.length == 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('cart_list')[0].innerHTML = emptyCart;
    }
  }
```

ok so what happens is upon adding an item into the cart and removing it, i get the message that is inside the span displayed correctly. BUT if the user adds again a item, the message wont disappear. Although i specified  `if (cartRows.length == 0)`

Comment: Are you calling `CartIsEmpty` again after the user adds an item to the cart?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call your function CartIsEmpty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, `addItemToCart()`, add this code in the beginning :

```js
let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_list')[0]
let cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart_item')

if (cartRows.length == 0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('cart_list')[0].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: it worked! BUT why? what did i exactly achieve by putting this at the beginn of `addItemToCart()`?

Comment: You could do this anywhere in the function before appending `cart_item` element to the list.